# Understanding android navigation drawer and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

i'm quite new to drawer material and i have trouble understanding some things:
I need to create an `Activity` with a `Fragment` on it. Different selections on the `Drawer` must replace the current `Fragment` with another one, but is the `Drawer` something in the fragment or it is one for the activity itself. More specifically is the `Drawer` living in the `Fragment` and if not is it possible to create it in the `Fragment`. I am asking this cause i see that when initiating the `Drawer` you need to fill parent activity. Also when i tried to use the `Navigation Drawer` template in `Android Studio` i didn't had the `Use a Fragment` checkbox.

Comment: See [here for an example project](https://github.com/devunwired/recyclerview-playground) which replaces fragments when using a navigation drawer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. But I think the simplest way is:

1) `DrawerLayout` view should reside in the activity (probably as the base layout).

2) When you click on an item in the draw 2 things happen:

- The fragment is replaced (you have one layout to contain the fragment and you just replace the fragment in it).
- The items inside the drawer update (if you are making a list you would simply set the data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Don't forget to save your state so it can recover in case the `Activity` is recreated.

Comment: When replacing the fragments does it matter if the call is `new instance` or just new Fragment()?

Comment: I like to instantiate my fragments when I add them in (and get rid of them when they are destroyed), but nothing is stopping you from holding them in the activity and using them when you replace the previous fragment (as long as you properly destroy the views that they hold once they are disconnected). However, holding a reference to a fragment might get you in trouble as the OS might recreate it for you and make your reference invalid.